# Do I need to play any of the previous GTA games before playing GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have never played a GTA game before but I have the chance to get GTA V. I'm wondering if it matters if I haven't played the previous games yet.

Do I need to play any of the previous games?

Comment: Voting to reopen. This question has been considered on-topic for so many other games and OP not using the magic words should not affect that.

Comment: Agreed with @Studoku... Although I cannot vote to reopen yet, I'm not sure why this was ever closed. This is probably the first time I've personally seen one of these sorts of questions closed. And it's not opinionated at all. If you need to play the previous to understand, the answer is clearly yes, if not, it's clearly no.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it does not matter. The GTA games do not have strong connections between them (barring the direct sequels or expansions, of which 5 is neither). You might miss some Easter eggs and/or references to older games/locations, but you will not miss anything significant.

Should you play the older games? That is subjective and I can't answer that for you. They're similar to 5, but each game has it's own systems and themes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, all GTA games have very independent stories from each other, you'll find in every game references to the others, but each one of them has its unique story, so, you wont be missing much by letting GTA V be the first of the series that you play.

I do recommend playing the other games though, simply because of the fact that they are all great games.